# Enabling IIS on VS 2017

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, iis

I am trying to get the option "IIS Express" to show up in my project on a new workstation

On my previous workstation for the same project it does show the IIS Express option
[image: workingg iis express]

On my new workstation for the same project ,the IIS express option is missing, I double checked that the IIS express is installed and able to start manually, am not sure why this option is not showing?any guidance on how to debug this?
[image: not working iis express]

UPDATE:

I tried
1.to repair and Modify didnt work, uninstalled and reinstalled the Visual studio with ASP.net,
2.I get the following error in the screenshot when I click on the "Start" button, it is actually a web based project

[image]
3.I can manually start the IIS express

Comment: As pointed out, either your IIS is not installed correctly, or the current project you have open is not a web application, but is desktop or some other type of project that is not web based. So, for desktop, or say a console application, then of course no web option will appear in the start button.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal - it is a web applilcation, I was able to run IIS Express on my old machine,I updated my question with I have try, any other suggestions you have to try ?

Comment: Are you sure that your current workstation has the same Dot.Net Framework as the previous one?

Comment: Based on that error message, that project is not being recognized as a web application.  Was this a web site, or a web site application? If this is a web site, then no sln file exists, and you would use file->open web site. If this is a web site application, then file->open project should and would work. What does the project settings show for the project type? (from that error message, it is CLEARLY showing the project type is a class, and not a web site application). So far, this suggests you are not opening a web site project, but only a class project.

Comment: all i need to do was "Set as start project" on a web applicaion project

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run repair from the Visual Studio Installer.

And make sure you have the ASP.NET and web development installed.

Visual Studio Installer->Visual Studio->Modify.
[image]

Comment: I updated my question with I have try, any other suggestions you have to try ?

Comment: About output type of the project you can find and change by the following steps: Right click on project in Solution Explorer -> Properties. In opened tab with properties select Application and there will be ComboBox marked with Output Type label.